# How to open a Matlab function

Tags: matlab, mex

Here in matlab, the source code for **latcfilt.m**

It is from signal processing toolbox.

```
error(nargchk(2,6,nargin,'struct'));

if nargin < 6
    [F,G,Zf] = latcfiltmex(varargin{:});
else
...
```

I want to have a look at the function **latcfiltmex()** , however, when I tried to rightclick->Open "latcfiltmex", it turned out that I cannot open it. It says the file latfiltmex.m doesn't exist.

Then how can I look into it?

Judging from its name, it appears to be a mex file. Then is it possible for me to get the c code for that? Or is it sealed by Mathworks?

Thanks

====

## Edit

I found the mex file in the %MATLAB%/toolbox/signal/ folder.
Its name is latcfiltmex.mexw32, and no attached src.

Comment: The "mex" within the file name "latcfiltmex" suggests that the file in question is a `.mex` file, that is, a pre-compiled matlab file. If so, the full file name is probably `latcfiltmex.mex` and source code cannot be viewed.

Comment: Exactly as Muster said. You can not see all matlab functions, some of them are not open to see.

Comment: Yeah, no source is found. Do you have an idea where can I get the implementation for a signal process function?

Comment: This must have been asked many times before. Surely a duplicate.

Comment: @woodchips find the dup and vote to close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For build-in functions and compiled mex  files Mathworks does not allow access to source code. All you have is the documentation published by mathworks.

Comment: Thanks. And @H.Muster has also brought out a answer in the comment.